# Porridge and monkeys dividing pancakes

Tags: riddle, word

> My beginning might be porridge,
>   My ending is all about dividing,
>   My middle is almost a monkey,
>   My whole is kind of like a pancake.

What am I?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Are you

> Paper?

My beginning might be porridge

> [Pap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pap_(food)) is a kind of porridge

My ending is all about dividing

> Per means division

My middle is almost a monkey

> An "ape" can refer to many primates, but not monkeys.

My whole is kind of like a pancake

> Both are flat

Comment: You got it! To be pedantic though, the "more general" in your 4th spoilertag is incorrect.

Comment: Oops. I'll fix it. I'm not a zoologist

Comment: @Randal'Thor I forgot to tell you after I fixed it. Is it correct now?

Comment: Yes, all correct. A green checkmark is in the post to you and will arrive within 6-8 weeks ;-)

Answer (score 8):

The pancake made me immediately think of

> The Universe

My beginning might be porridge,

> People talk in science about the "perfect conditions," like Goldilock's porridge, as having been needed for the origin of the universe.

My ending is all about dividing,

> The outer edge of the unvierse is expanding, each point on the sphere of the bubble must divide.

My middle is almost a monkey,

> The ["monkey theorem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem) is all about *approaching* infinity, which the middle of the universe is constantly doing.  Maybe one day it'll get there? :)

My whole is kind of like a pancake.

> The Universe may well be shaped more like a pancake than a perfect sphere, just like so many galaxies and the cells of so many carbon-based lifeforms.

Comment: It's a bit of a stretch, but nice one nonetheless! +1

Comment: So, the Universe is as flat as the Earth?

Comment: @xhienne Don't be silly. The universe isn't that flat... :)

Comment: @xhienne Nope. The earth is the flattest :P